# Observable.zip() being executed asynchronously

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm coding an Android App, using RxJava, Retrofit and the Clean Architecture. The thing is that I have an Interactor/UseCase that needs to return the collection of favorite teams and favorite players. The collection of favorite teams is the results from one endpoint mixed with another. Same thing for the favorite players. In the Interactor/UseCase implementation I'm doing something like this:

```
getTeams = Observable.merge(mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllTeams(), mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllFavoriteTeams());
getPlayers = Observable.merge(mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllPlayers(), mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllFavoritePlayers());
```

Then I'm zipping this two responses together returning them in a single wrapper object:

```
Observable.zip(getTeams, getPlayers, new Func2<List<Team>, List<Player>, Pair<List<Team>, List<Player>>>() {
    @Override
    public Pair<List<Team>, List<Player>> call(List<Team> teamList, List<Player> players) {
        return new Pair<>(teamList, players);
    }
}).subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<Pair<List<Team>, List<Player>>>() {

    @Override
    public void onNext(Pair<List<Team>, List<Player>> pair) {
        callback.showResultOnUI(pair);
    }

});
```

I know that the .zip() method is supposed to wait until the two rx.Observables end emitting the items, but in this case the mixing method is being executed more than one time.

My question is; Is there a way to keep the zip's merging method from being executed more than once?

Keep in mind this things:

- I simplified the example. I'm actually also merging a cache rx.Observable with the Retrofit's rx.Observables.
- The endpoints can't change. The wrapper object can't change. The response must be returned to te UI in a sigle object wrapper. We can't send the favorite teams and the favorite players in two different callback methods.

Comment: You maybe could pass a empty stuff to downstream using startWith(). And zip that with a Team that you already have. And pass the new one when you get the async job done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get that, could you explain it a little more?

Comment: `getAllTeams` and `getAllFavoriteTeams` return `Observable<List<Team>>`, and so 'Players'.(I think in fact the `Observable` is `Single` by their names.) So mixing method being executed more than one time is correct. Actually, it will be executed 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `zip` method gets called multiple times because you act on `List<T>`s. This means that this Observable:

```
getTeams = Observable.merge(
      mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllTeams(), 
      mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllFavoriteTeams());
```

Will have 2 items, each one a list - it won't merge them all together. What you want is to merge both lists into one:

```
getTeams = Observable.merge(
      mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllTeams(), 
      mNetworkRetrofitService.getAllFavoriteTeams())
.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable()
.toList();
```

If you do this for both of your `zip` parameters, then you will get only one emission.

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna try it. How it would be the version without using lambdas?, specifically the `.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable()` line.

Comment: Well, do iterative expansion - `.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)` becomes `.flatMap(o -> Observable.fromIterable(o))` which becomes `.flatMap(new Func1<Observable<List<Team>, Observable<Team>>() { ... })` - Sorry, it's so much easier with lambda's it's not even funny.

Comment: hahaha yeah I know, but we have tons of legacy code that we're trying to improve and using lambdas is still a pending milestone.